# PC CPU case materials?

Tags: packages

Typically, there is a CPU with a flat metallic top which is connected to the heatsink with a thermal conductive grease. What metal is the top of the CPU package?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's called the IHS, or integrated heat spreader. It's apparently made from copper or a copper alloy (and nickel plated). There's another (organic) material between the die itself and the IHS. Intel reportedly will not tell you the exact composition of the IHS without a signed NDA in hand (and, presumably, a moving story as to why you need to know and why Intel should tell you).

Edit: If the description "nickel plated copper" is good enough for you, that appears in some Intel [datasheets](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/datasheets/core-i7-900-ee-and-desktop-processor-series-datasheet-vol-1.pdf):

[image: http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/datasheets/core-i7-900-ee-and-desktop-processor-series-datasheet-vol-1.pdf]

To verify this, you should be able to detect slight ferromagnetism with a rare-earth magnet from the nickel plating, and scratching it (someplace unimportant if it's a working chip) should let the color of the underlying alloy show. In the past, aluminum alloy has been used.

Comment: I was wondering about its possible reaction with gallium based  thermal greases. Nickel is probably OK, but not copper.

Answer (score 1):

In modern CPUs, they use a "flip-chip" design. The metallic-looking surface is actually the bottom of the silicon wafer on which the chip is manufactured. This method allows the least amount of material between the CPU and heatsink. Any additional materials would impede the flow of heat.

Older CPUs were capped with aluminum, which was effectively an intermediate heatsink/heat-spreader.

Comment: Are you sure? This i7 case top does not look like part of the chip itself http://ic.tweakimg.net/ext/i/1294043445.jpeg

Comment: While you are right that this is a "flip chip", the chip die is not exposed. The bottom of the die is attached to the metal lid. The lid provides good thermal transfer to the heatsink while protecting the die.